# Правильно ли составлено предложение (пунктуация и смысловая часть)?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, смысл

Есть небольшой кусок текста. Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Может его можно как-то сократить, чтобы он смотрелся более органично? На сюжет не обращайте внимания:)

Текст:

"**В восемь вечера я хотел съездить к тебе домой, но передумал ввиду проблем как личного, так и личностного характера. На сегодняшний день я могу с полной уверенностью сказать, что готов. Поэтому если ты, вдруг, не обиделась на меня, то я буду искренне рад приехать к тебе домой. Правда, есть одна серьёзная проблема: приехать я смогу только вечером, а не днём**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*В восемь вечера я хотел **заехать** к тебе домой, но передумал ввиду проблем как личного, так и личностного характера. На сегодняшний день я могу с полной уверенностью сказать, что готов. **И если** ты **вдруг** не обиделась на меня, то  буду искренне **рад приехать**. Правда, есть одна серьёзная проблема: **это возможно** только вечером, а не днём".*

Знаки препинания расставлены в основном верно, в тексте убраны повторы слов, в том числе личных местоимений.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: Откуда взялось «возможно»? Чем плохо было «приехать я смогу...»? «Съездить» в смысле «заехать»  — это как бы нормально,)) а вот «смогу приехать», видите ли, не годится!